# Buffon's needle in one dimension

Tags: probability, problem-solving, geometric-probability

I want to solve Buffon's Needle problem but first I was trying to tackle a simpler case.

So: consider an infinite line with points each $t$ units. Let's say that we have a "needle" of length $L\leq t$ which we throw. I claim the probability of the needle not touching any point is given by:

$$
P = \frac{t-L}{t} = 1 -\frac{L}{t}
$$

That's because we have a length of size $t-L$ where the needle can lie and the total length between points is $t$

Now, in the 2D case we simply consider $P_\theta = 1 - \frac{L\sin(\theta)}{t}$ (i.e., the projection of the needle's length along the y axis) and sum (integrate) from $0$ to $\pi$.

However the result differs from the usual $\left(\frac{2L}{\pi t}\right)$. Am I missing something in the integration? Or maybe the reasoning from the 1D case is incorrect?

Thanks for your advise

Comment: You need to _average_ $P_\theta$ over $\theta\sim U(0,\,\pi)$, giving $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi P_\theta\mathrm{d}\theta=1-\frac{2L}{t\pi}$.

Comment: "However the result differs from the usual:" Going forward with your future MathSE postings, it is not a good idea to make a raw statement, such as the one  that I have quoted, without showing detailed work, directly in the posting.